# What do I need to know to set up a business to accept cryptocurrency through the stellar blockchain

Tags: business

What legalities would be involved in the US? I've only dabbled in programming here and there and seem to be jumping around. Where would someone start on a project like this, I've got the time to learn. I just need some idea of what order to go in.

Answer (score 1):

Not legal advice here for the record. As far as I'm aware you should do kyc and aml checks. The compliance server for anchors can automate this, however I'm not sure how to automate looking up the names and addresses to check if they are on a sanctions list. Maybe someone else on here might know how?

Answer (score 0):

I found this along with some other information on creating stellar QR codes. However the plugin only works with wordpress.

http://mwplug.com/ & https://cwaqrgen.com/xlm

Seems simple enough for what I need to do. As far as what I've found out so far,  There's no legalities preventing me from say going to a small business and educating them on how easy it can be to just print out a wallet and accept cryptocurrency. All while explaining the risks and volatility as well as how to keep detailed records for taxes.